# Query a table on a remote SQL Server to process and display in formatted way?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to query a table on a remote SQL Server to process and then display the data in a formatted matter.

When I try this it keeps throwing an exception and saying

> Specified cast is not valid

I have included the class where I am running the query. I have taken out the real details of connecting to my server for obvious reasons. This is the contents [contents of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Gky.png) of my database. I do not need the customer id but I do need the rest of the columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
static class CustomerRepository
{
    private static string connString = "Server=xxxx.com;"
                                     + "Database=xxxxxx;"
                                     + "User ID=xxxxxx;"
                                     + "Password=xxxxxx;"
                                     + "Integrated Security=False;";

    public static CustomerCollection getAllCustomers()
    {
        CustomerCollection customers;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            string query = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}"
                                        , "SELECT CompanyName, Address, City, Province, PostalCode, CreditHold"
                                        , "FROM Customer"
                                        , "ORDER BY CompanyName");
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                conn.Open();

                customers = new CustomerCollection();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    string companyName;
                    string address = null;
                    string city = null;
                    string province = null;
                    string postalCode = null;
                    bool creditHold = false;

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        companyName = reader["CompanyName"] as string;

                        if (!reader.IsDBNull(1))
                        {
                            address = reader[1] as string;
                        }

                        if (!reader.IsDBNull(2))
                        {
                            city = reader[2] as string;
                        }

                        if (!reader.IsDBNull(3))
                        {
                            province = reader[3] as string;
                        }

                        if (!reader.IsDBNull(4))
                        {
                            postalCode = reader[4] as string;
                        }

                        if (!reader.IsDBNull(5))
                        {
                            creditHold = (bool)reader[5];
                        }

                        customers.Add(new CustomerInfo(companyName, address, city, province, postalCode, creditHold));
                    }

                    return customers;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the line causing the error this one: creditHold = (bool)reader[5];? If so, the value you get from db cannot be cast to bool. Try with bool.TryParse or some custom logic for checking the value.

Comment: The value is a tinyint in the database and if I'm not mistaken a tinyint can be directly converted to  a bool in c# because the value is either 0 or 1 for false or true respectively. Would the tryParse method make a difference?

Comment: _tinyint can be directly converted to a bool_ - it is not possible because `tinyint` is 8 bit size and `bool` is 1 bit size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most possible reason of error is invalid casting of Sql type `Tinyint` value to .NET type `bool` value in column number 5
First retrive data from `SqlDataReader` with correspondent .NET type (`Tinyint` to `byte`)
Then use your logic to convert `Byte` value to `bool`

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(5))
{
    byte rawCreditHold = reader.GetByte(5);
    creditHold = (rawCreditHold == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `creditHold = (bool)reader[5];` with

```
if (reader[5].ToString() == "1")
{
    creditHold = true;
}
else
{
    creditHold = false;
}
```

Comment: when I do this it sets all the values to false, even thought I know that a few of them are true.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    while (reader.read())
    {
            if (reader["CompanyName"] != System.DBNull.Value) companyName = Convert.ToString(reader["CompanyName"]);
            if (reader["Address "] != System.DBNull.Value) address  = Convert.ToString(reader["Address"]);
            if (reader["City"] != System.DBNull.Value) city = Convert.ToString(reader["City"]);
            if (reader["PostalCode"] != System.DBNull.Value) postalCode  = Convert.ToString(reader["PostalCode"]);
            if (reader["Province"] != System.DBNull.Value) province  = Convert.ToString(reader["Province"]);
            if (reader["CreditHold"] != System.DBNull.Value) creditHold = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["CreditHold"]);
            customers.Add(new CustomerInfo(companyName, address, city, province, postalCode, creditHold));
    }
```

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean(reader["CreditHold"])` throw Exception because type of database column is `Tinyint`